# is it possible to select child element when you click on parent element in react, and the add a class to the parent element after an event

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am making a game with react, it's a memory game where you match images.so what I want to archive is, when I click on the div it selects the child of the div(the image) and then add class to the parent and then add class to the child itself. Based on the game logic I have to select the the child element first then if pass some conditions I  then add a class to it and it's parent element. look at the code I currently have but it's not working, please help me out.
`

```
let currentElement;
const imageclick=(e)=>{
    //select current image
    currentElement=e.target.firstElementChild;
    // some game  logic the add class to child and parent
    //add class to parent
    currentElement.closest("div").classList.add("show");
    //add class to child
    currentElement.classList.remove("hidden")
}

const app=()=>{
    return(
        <div className="imgDiv transition" key={i} onClick={imageclick}>
        <img src={img} alt="" className="tileImage hidden" />
        </div>
    )
}
```

`

Comment: Modifying DOM directly in React isn't a good practice. You should rather use state to make changes.

Comment: I am modifying like 16 elements so do you still advice I use state, and since it's a memory game all the element are arranged at random every time

Comment: Yes, even if you would modify 10000 elements.  Don't use React if you don't want to use React.

Comment: please can you show me how to do it with state just for one div and one image

Comment: you can use `childRef.current.focus()` to focus a child element.

Comment: You didn't provide much information of what should happen, but you can check this https://codesandbox.io/s/fast-bash-7wgdpz?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple approaches.

One way is to store your images in an array of objects. This array is used to render all of your images. You could even shuffle the array to make the order random.

Inside your component you have a state. This state tracks the index of the currently selected image of the array. The initial state can be `null` to indicate that there is no current selected image.

While looping over your images, check for each image if the `selectedImageIndex` is equal to the index of the current image. If so, pass some extra classes.

(You don't need to toggle `hidden` class on the image. Use the `show` class on the div to either show or hide the child image).

Pass the `index` of the current image to the `imageClick` function in the `onClick` handler of the `div`. Whenever we click an image, we want to set the `index` of the image as our `selectedImageIndex`.

The component will now rerender and add the class to the clicked `div`.

---

### Edit

I've modified the answer according to your comment. This example allows for 2 indexes to be stored into the state that tracks the selected images.

Whenever you click the same, the image is deselected. Whenever you click another image it will add its `index` to the state.

In the `useEffect` hook you can asses if the images corresponding to the indexes have a similar `src` or other property that matches.

(I would recommend creating a more robust system in which YOU say which images are the same instead of depending on the URL to be the same. E.g. two images can be the same while having different URL's)

```
const images = [
  {
    id: 'A',
    src: 'your-image.jpg',
    alt: 'Something about your image'
  },
  {
    id: 'B'
    src: 'your-other-image.jpg',
    alt: 'Something about your image'
  },
  {
    id: 'A' // The match to the other A
    src: 'the-other-image-that-matches-the-first.jpg',
    alt: 'Something about your image'
  }
];

const App = () => {
  const [selectedImageIndexes, setSelectedImageIndexes] = useState([null, null]);

  const imageClick = index => {
    setSelectedImageIndex(currentIndexes => {
      // If the same index is clicked, deselect all.
      if (currentIndexes.includes(index)) {
        return [null, null];
      }

      // If no indexes have been set.
      if (currentIndexes.every(index => index === null)) {
        return [index, null];
      }

      // Set the second clicked image.
      return [currentIndexes[0], index];
    });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    // If both indexes are set.
    if (selectedImageIndexes.every(index => index !== null) {
      
      /**
       * With the indexes in the selectedImageIndexes state,
       * check if the images corresponding to the indexes are matches.
       */
      if (selectedImageIndexes[0].id === selectedImageIndexes[1].id) {
        // Match!
      }
    }
  }, [selectedImageIndexes]);

  return (
    <div className="images">
      {images.map((image, index) => {
        const className = selectedImageIndex.includes(index) ? 'show' : '';

        return (
          <div className="imgDiv transition" key={`img-div-${index}`} onClick={() => imageClick(index)}>
            <img src={image.src} className="tileImage" alt={image.alt} />
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  )
};
```

Comment: I really appreciate this. Thank you but I want to shed more light on the question. This is how the code should work, if I click an image it makes it visible, then when I click another image it compares the source of the first image and the second image if they are the same, both of the images will remain showing. if the sources are not the same then I hide the first image again . from the code you gave me I can only hide one image at a time. Though I have already done the project with javascript I am having a hard time doing it with react. Thank you

Comment: and this the code I currently have https://i.ibb.co/sFRqhhK/stackoverflow.png

Comment: I've added a more complete answer based on the feedback in your comment. This system will now account for 2 indexes.